# Adjust(Resize) the Copy/Paste action bar context menu on ICS phones/tablets

Tags: android, copy-paste, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-actionbar

On the browser app, when I try to do a copy paste, the context menu size(height of the items) are nice and thin. But when inside one of my application, on a webview, I initiate the copy paste, the resulting action bar's context menu(menu items) is huge and doesn't look nice.

Attaching the screenshots. Is there any way to fix this?

[image: Browser app's screenshot]
[image: My App's screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Found the answer. If you compile the app with minSDKversion less than 11, you will get these huge ugly context menu. 11 and up, the menu items are nice and thin.

Can I change/alter the context menu item's sizes? Doesn't seem to be possible.